# Reflected and refracted wave sphased

Tags: optics, waves, reflection, refraction, plane-wave

When we derive refraction and reflection laws for a generical plane wave on a surface, we say that reflected and refracted must be in phase with the incident wave. Why a medium cannot do a sphased reaction beside incident wave? Sorry for my trivial question.

Comment: Is this title a typo? I don't know what the word 'sphased' means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Take a look at [phase conjugated mirror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_conjugate_mirror#Optical_phase_conjugation) on Wikipedia.

Also, phase shifts do happen on reflection from flat surfaces -- all the time. It's called the [Goos-Hänchen effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goos-Hanchen_effect). It's just very very small, so that's probably why you ignore it in your derivation.

Comment: Thank for the answer! Phase conjugated mirror is optically non linear: do you mean that this effect is a non linear effect? If yes, why in linear conditions you haven't phase shifts in reflection?

Comment: A phase conjugated mirror's effect is non-linear, but the Goos-Hänchen effect takes place in linear media. It has to do with the penetration depth of the wave into the medium, if I remember correctly.